# Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem: The request is not supported

Tags: windows, docker, windows-container

```
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 38d5975c4992c39b5ee8f5a46ad19f45435ff59b18523e3552c53b24ab23f1ca: The request is not supported.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"38d5975c4992c39b5ee8f5a46ad19f45435ff59b18523e3552c53b24ab23f1ca","Owner":"docker",
"IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\38d5975c4992c39b5ee8f5a46ad19f45435ff59b18523e3552c53b24ab23f1ca",
"Layers":[{"ID":"6658b069-0c9a-5796-8dd4-df51d8e89bf3","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e984e14da4691b4ca5782a9c4b4af88a17db410424d2632d157a261b8d2cd918"},
{"ID":"7b2926d2-514d-5e06-82e3-f9a726c336a6","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\d239cc65931aeaa6443dd51452405e442baf32447515ecb3b19aee1a86b3e616"},
{"ID":"f87666ff-622a-57ae-a59c-935bcbd517ab","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\c09e132f538143279663778ef82c57af1d1d9af79f47963bf1e543919e9e363e"},
{"ID":"04ca5ecc-0c68-586c-baf1-85fbc7dae2ed","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\110cc8554b1db358e3394b0aecbbbf17135775eaabd7e19587bcc081a146dc3f"},
{"ID":"4d028b02-ef55-5ef6-9418-27439f950375","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\c4b0fef4a4f026def338d79ba686f3838e9d217f79ed8b5f0a10edf911ee2312"},
{"ID":"6f35449b-a2ff-50a1-9a4a-bb57e59dcd54","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\34aa11cc4d8dd2044c5674e4f76ab7766289bf5a7fac0db10b5f3b165bcc7621"},
{"ID":"ccbb1200-37f1-53b2-ab77-0e80099c90e7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7ff5467f7724bfc90ece4ef3001a186b7fd047d474ffae7e0d51ca351b746eab"},
{"ID":"d4312109-22d8-55e2-a97e-e676cbdd3f81","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3439d5d471045fc013503367e69e349ee4210f5802a8517c999d4be118c99c4a"},
{"ID":"14f30d2a-c510-5be8-a7cd-2d4984c1b10b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\987438c0b2a45e8aafea8858933f8ba4b87ec34ee53ffea747acb30169f180a7"},
{"ID":"d14333f6-a148-555b-a891-db7b0ff9814f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\9bc15a6f050a3708d37f562ab973e9e6db7d136c592f5dc07201ca66ede2d614"},
{"ID":"a04c176c-27f5-557f-87f1-6dcd9beab874","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\9f413da158b62b375939235fa7a1529069d5a711beffb69a814663145fc276f9"},
{"ID":"95f19e14-436b-5e5f-9fd6-997b9ad17a8e","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\8f3913fbde770ec14c8af226501fb4af3bdde356c7e3de1b6cd5a3a48544f2b6"}],
"HostName":"38d5975c4992","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["8dbee51c-78ac-4bf7-8d7b-42cbf1485fdc"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter
\\9f413da158b62b375939235fa7a1529069d5a711beffb69a814663145fc276f9\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
```

I'm getting the above issue still.
OS: Windows 10 Home (Hyper-v Enabled, Virtualization is enabled, Docker desktop is up & running)

When I try to run my docker image (`docker run -p 8085:8085 app`), I ve got the above issue.

I've already raised an issue in github (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41998) Meanwhile does anyone can help?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error message (with a different hash value) when I was running Docker's hello world from the [installation tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-server-and-client-binaries-on-windows) using the command:

```
&$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\docker run hello-world:nanoserver
```

I fixed this error by going to `Control Panel` > `Turn Windows features on or off` and enabling `Containers` and then rebooting.

[image]

It seems that `Hyper-V` and `Windows Hypervisor Plateform` are not needed to run this hello world.

I am running Windows 10 Professional Build 19044 and Docker 20.10.14.

Comment: Note that `Containers` feature isn't on Windows Home.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/system-requirements

Comment: On Windows 11. I had Hyper-V enabled because I was running some small test VMs. However, Containers was unchecked, so I wound up here after googling. Thanks for the answer. Still useful a year later.